# What Databases would be recommended for historical data with over 500M rows and data ingested daily?

Tags: database-design, big-data

I'm wondering what Databases would best be suited for storing historical data for multiple clients with over 500M rows and incremental data ingested daily per client?  Since data would be used for analysis and reporting quick query performance would also need to be taken into consideration.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Talk to [this guy](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/331848/sql-server-2022-configuration) I guess

Answer (score 1):

> I'm wondering what Databases would best be suited for storing historical data for multiple clients with over 500M rows and incremental data ingested daily per client?

Any database, there is no "*best*" based on the parameters you've provided. Generally it's good to pick one that is more mainstream and well documented, with an actual user base. This makes it easier to find solutions when you're stuck on a problem (as is true with any software).

If your data is structured and you don't mind maintaining schema changes, then some of the main RDBMS out there are: Microsoft SQL Server, PostgreSQL, Oracle SQL, MySQL, MariaDB.

If your data is highly unstructured or changes at a rate outside of what you're able to maintain, then the most mainstream NoSQL database is probably MongoDB.

If you need something in the cloud with more automated maintenance (backups, availability zones, data retention, etc) then Azure or AWS has options (e.g. Azure SQL Database).

Picking a database system has almost nothing to do with the size of the data.

Comment: @Vérace Good thing I didn't mention it. 

Comment: On reflection, you are corret, this has nothing to do with licensing - it is however a shopping-list question znd  as such, not on-topic here!

Comment: @Vérace That I agree with. Apparently it's still encouraged to answer questions that should be closed anyway. 